# Ajax using cakephp 2.x and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

i have been looking for more than two days now for an answer to this issue and no luck at all. Im trying to use ajax with jquery and cakephp. I am using this jquery function:

```
$("#pais").change(function(){ 

$.ajax({ data: "id=" + document.getElementById('pais').value, 
         type: "GET", 
         url: "http://localhost/facebook/Countries/getTeam/", 
         success: function(data){ 
             $('#cuadro').show();
             pais();
        } 
    }); 
});
```

I need to send 1 value for my controller's function "getteam($id= null)" but when i check with firebug what im actually sending i can see that it ads "?id=4" and i need to have something like /controller/action/id.

how do you get this with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I misunderstood what you are asking, but wouldn't it be as simple as:

```
$("#pais").change(function(){ 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "http://localhost/facebook/Countries/getTeam/" + document.getElementById('pais').value, 
        success: function(data){ 
            $('#cuadro').show();
            pais();
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to build url manually like below

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", 
         url: "http://localhost/facebook/Countries/getTeam/"+document.getElementById('pais').value, 
         success: function(data){ 
             $('#cuadro').show();
             pais();
        } 
    });
```

Comment: my bad.i cant believe i didnt try this... sometimes you just feel like not doint it simple... haha. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try appending your id onto the URL string, and not passing anything in the data param. Like this:

```
$("#pais").change(function(){ 

    $.ajax({ 
         type: "GET", 
         url: "http://localhost/facebook/Countries/getTeam/"+document.getElementById('pais').value, 
         success: function(data){ 
             $('#cuadro').show();
             pais();
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: oh my... why i didnt try this!... good lord, this kind of things makes me want to be chef or taxi driver :P